# conversion of byte array to image

Tags: android

I want to convert a byte array to an image ,For that I used the code

```
final BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decrpt));
```

where Decrypt is the byte array,It showing error in ImageIO.I dont know what is that parameter pls help me to sort it out.

Comment: Can you attach the logcat error message?.

Comment: Corrected that plm with     Bitmap bitmapimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decrpt, 0, decrpt.length);

Comment: kindly write your answer down and close this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hope this code will help you:

```
byte[] data = item1.getBytes();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```