# Open an Image with byte array in device image broswer

Tags: android, image, uri

I'm having a bytearray of an image. I need to display the image using device image broswer.

I used this code to open an image which is having the URI which is working fine

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
Uri u = Uri.fromFile(destinationFile);
intent.setDataAndType(u, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Problem** I dont have an URI i just having an image byte array. So how can i acheive this

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: i think image in your project like drawable folder

Comment: Its not a image..Its a byte array

Comment: i know but where is image of byte array like sdcard or drawable  resource

Comment: I have that byte array in that SDCard with in just a file

Comment: we can also get the uri of sdcard image why u nedd bytearray

Comment: I'm having the file as encrypted byte array file. So i will decrypt and i wanna show!

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
imageview.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Source: [conversion of byte array to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208748/conversion-of-byte-array-to-image)