# I saved it as a blob in db using ByteArrayInputStream, I want blob image get into ByteArrayInputStream on android

Tags: android

Current I my capture image insert DB.

```
try {
    PreparedStatement statement = mConnection.prepareStatement(insertCapPic);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(picdata); //picdata is byte[]
    statement.setBlob(1, bis);
 }
```

so capture image is stored in db in blob format.

[image]

I want to import this blob data back into byte format (byte or bitmap or ByteArrayInputStream)

select blob data class

```
try {
    mStatement = mConnection.createStatement();
    mStatement.executeQuery("use be");

    String getPicData ="select pic from table where -----";

    statement = mConnection.prepareStatement(getPicData);
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        // I want blob data to byte format.
    }
```

how to this problem?
if you know , please advice me .
thanks:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conversion of byte array to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208748/conversion-of-byte-array-to-image)